# How to iterate through following compex JSON data and access its all values including nested?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON data but I don't know how to iterate through it and read its all values:

```
var students = {
  "student1": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "age": 24,
    "subject": [{
        "name": "IT",
        "marks": 85
      },
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "marks": 75
      },
      {
        "name": "English",
        "marks": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  "student2": {
    "first_name": "David",
    "last_name": "Silva",
    "age": 22,
    "subject": [{
        "name": "IT",
        "marks": 85
      },
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "marks": 75
      },
      {
        "name": "English",
        "marks": 60
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I would like to use following methods to do the needful:

1. Using for in loop
2. Using simple for loop
3. Using $.each in jQuery

I will prefer to display above values in `<ul> <li>` nicely formatted.

Also, please suggest me what will be look of above JSON data if I put it in an external .json file?

Comment: what does your current attempt to do those things look like? You are basically asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: no, not at all, just wondering how to do we all this. want to learn and know...

Comment: Did you do a google search for *'how to iterate js array'*?

Comment: Yes, but I am facing problem in iterating through nested arrays.

Comment: well post your current code so we can see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for in` loop to iterate over the object, as it iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order, and needs to use `.hasOwnProperty`, unless inherited properties want to be shown.

Now about accessing the object, let's say I have a `JSON` like

```
var myJson={name:"john",age:22,email:"email@domain.com"};
```

and I need to access the value of `name` i would simply use `.` operator using the `myJson` variable i.e `console.log(myJson.name)` will output `john`. because it will be treated as an object, now if I make a little change and make the object like below

```
var myJson=[{name:"john",age:22,email:"email@domain.com"}];
```

now if you try to access the value of the property `name` with the same statement above you will get `undefined` because the `[]` will now treat it as an object(JSON) with an array of 1 person or a `JSON Array`, now if you access it like `console.log(myJson[0].name)` it will print `john` in `console` what if there was more than one person in the array? then it will look like following

```
var myJson=[
    {name:"john",age:22,email:"john@domain.com"},
    {name:"nash",age:25,email:"nash@domain.com"}
];
```

`console.log(myJson[0].name)` will print `john` and `console.log(myJson[1].name)` will print `nash` so as I mentioned in the start that you should use `for in` loop for iterating over an object and if we want to print all the names of the person in the `JSON Array` it will be like.

```
for(var person in myJson){

    console.log(myJson[person].name, myJson[person].age, myJson[person].email);


}
```

it will output in the console like below

```
john, 22, john@domain.com
nash, 25, nash@domain.com
```

I have tried to keep it simple so that you understand you can look into [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), in your case you have  a nested object in which property/key `subject` is an array so if I want to access the `first_name` of `student1` i will write `students.student1.first_name` and if I want to print the `name` of the first `subject` of `student1` I will write `students.student1.subject[0].name`

Below is a sample script to print all the students along with their subjects and marks and personal information since you `JSON` is nested I am using a nested `for in`, although Nested iterations are not necessarily a bad thing, even many well-known algorithms rely on them. But you have to be extremely cautious what you execute in the in the nested loops.

For the sake of understanding and keeping the given example of `json` object, i am using the same to make a snippet. Hope it helps you out

```js
var students = {
  "student1": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "age": 24,
    "subject": [{
        "name": "IT",
        "marks": 85
      },
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "marks": 75
      },
      {
        "name": "English",
        "marks": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  "student2": {
    "first_name": "David",
    "last_name": "Silva",
    "age": 22,
    "subject": [{
        "name": "IT",
        "marks": 85
      },
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "marks": 75
      },
      {
        "name": "English",
        "marks": 60
      }
    ]
  }
};


$("#print").on('click', function() {
  for (var student in students) {
    console.log(students[student].first_name + '-' + students[student].last_name);
    for (var subject in students[student].subject) {
      console.log(students[student].subject[subject].name, students[student].subject[subject].marks);
    }
  }
  setTimeout('console.clear()', 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="print" value="print-now">
```